# React createElement error when trying to import in another class using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i have a component called SEO.tsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
export default class SEO extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>test</div>
        );
    }
}
```

in pageEvents.tsx i'm trying to call above component

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import SEO from '../components/SEO/SEO';
    class PageEvent extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (< SEO />);
        }
    }
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined
SEO.render
src/components/SEO/SEO.tsx:4
  1 | import React, { Component } from 'react'
  2 | export default class SEO extends Component {
  3 |     render() {
> 4 |         return (
  5 |             <div>test</div>
  6 |         );
  7 |     }
```

Comment: import `React` in `pageEvents.tsx` file.

Comment: I have already done that but it still doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a weird error I think it specific to TypeScript. You have to import React in the SEO component just like you did in the PageEvent component. The other import format is not working in Typescript, although I have met with it in various examples.

```js
import * as React from "react";

export default class SEO extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>test</div>;
  }
}
```

Here is an [example code](https://codesandbox.io/s/pjknlqm890)

Comment: So,if we need to test hundreds of components we should import with asterisk in whole app,unaceptable.

Comment: @Goran_Ilic_Ilke Fortunately this limitation is no longer in Typescript you can import react in the current version the usual way. ```import React, { Component } from 'react'```

Comment: Not working in my starter pack buddy,i still gett error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined.

Comment: I think than ts-jest simply doesnt work compilation in ->  transform: {
    '\\.(ts|tsx)$': 'ts-jest',
  }, should be but thats not the case.